# Customize Android ActionBar

Tags: android, styles, android-actionbar

I searched a lot and couldn't solve my problem.
I want to customize my app's action bar.

I'm calling the actiong this way:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
 super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
 /*
  *  menu.add(int groupId, int itemId, int order, CharSequence title);
  */
 MenuItem menu0 = menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Action Item 0");
 {
  menu0.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
  menu0.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
 }
 return true;
}
```

And my style.xml:

```
<resources>

<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">#CCCCCC</item>
</style>
```

However the textcolor remains in default (# FFF), have tried everything and do not know where I'm going wrong, I appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to change the colour of ? Action Menu ?

Comment: The color of the App Title in the ActionBar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you guys, I did what I want by this tutorial: http://shreymalhotra.me/blog/tutorial/android/android-create-custom-themes-for-your-apps/

Added this on onCreate():

```
final ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
```

And to change the title color my style.xml look like this:

```
    <style name="Theme.MyAppTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Theme.MyAppTheme.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.MyAppTheme.ActionBar" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/Theme.MyAppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.MyAppTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ccc</item>
</style>
```

Obs: Im not sure, but I think that my first style will work with that line on the oncreate() method.

Comment: Either explain/summarize what was in the linky (prevent link-rot! **FYI**) or this should rather be a comment and not an answer!

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">#CCCCCC</item>
    <item name="textColor">#CCCCCC</item>
</style>
```

Sometimes because of the API you use, removing **android:** works

also try to define the color in `color.xml` and use this way:

```
 <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/mColor</item>
        <item name="textColor">@color/mColor</item>
 </style>
```

**EDIT:**

```
<style name="MyActionBar"parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextColor">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextColor</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar.TitleTextColor" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/mColor</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I'm using min API 8. Eclipse don't let me run. In the items without the "android:" shows this: "No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'textColor'"

Comment: Eclipse isn't recognizing the attr "android:titleTextColor", I don't understand why ...